# WildFly 10 + Spring Security + JSF + CDI não injeta dependência

Tags: java, cdi

Estou tentando implementar CDI em um projeto WEB que tenho onde utilizo WildFly10 com Spring Security (login personalizado) e JSF e não estou conseguindo injetar dependencias.

No Exemplo abaixo o UsuarioDao quando é utilizado da

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   br.com.transportesalvorada.security.configall.ServicoDetalhamentoUsuario.loadUserByUsername(ServicoDetalhamentoUsuario.java:39)

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import br.com.transportesalvorada.security.bean.Usuario;
import br.com.transportesalvorada.security.dao.UsuarioDao;


@Service("servicoDetalhamentoUsuario")
public class ServicoDetalhamentoUsuario implements UserDetailsService, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject 
    private UsuarioDao usuarioDao;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("\n---[ServicoDetalhamentoUsuario]--------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n email :"+ email);

        //usuarioDao = new UsuarioDao();
        Usuario usuario = usuarioDao.consulta(email);

        if(usuario != null && usuario.getEmail() != null){
            System.out.println("\n usuario :"+usuario.getEmail());
            System.out.println("\n grupos  :"+usuario.getGrupos().size());
            return new UsuarioSistema(usuario, getGrupo(usuario));
        }
        return  null;



    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrupo(Usuario usuario) {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grupos = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        usuario.getGrupos().forEach(g->{
            grupos.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(g.getNome().toUpperCase()));
        });
        return grupos;
    }

}


import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import br.com.transportesalvorada.modeldao.dao.JpaUtil;
import br.com.transportesalvorada.security.bean.Usuario;


public class UsuarioDao implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Usuario consulta(String email) {

        System.out.println("\n -------- Entrou no Usuario.consulta - antes do EM");

        EntityManager entityManager = new JpaUtil().geraEM();
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        try{
            TypedQuery<Usuario> query = entityManager.createQuery("select u from Usuario u where u.email = :pEmail",Usuario.class);
            query.setParameter("pEmail", email);
            usuario = query.getSingleResult();
            usuario.getGrupos().size();
            return usuario;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("\n Erro %s \n" , e);
        }   
        return usuario;
    }


}
```

Minha estrutura de Projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Pom.xml

```
     <dependencies>
        <!--  Testes JUnit-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CDI teste --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jglue.cdi-unit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-unit</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Configuracao de Persistencia 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId> 
            <artifactId>perolawebmodelsecurit</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.0</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId> 
            <artifactId>perolawebmodeldao</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.0</version> 
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!--  Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
            <version>6.0</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>  
            <version>1.0.10</version>  
        </dependency>

        <!--  Quando for WildFly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-jsf</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  CDI -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
           <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  DB-Postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  JPA-Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--  Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: O erro é nessa linha:  Usuario usuario = usuarioDao.consulta(email) ?

Comment: Isso. Nesta linha mesmo. Mas na verdade essa é só um exemplo. Não funciona em lugar nenhum.

Comment: Na pasta META-INF cria um arquivo chamado beans.xml, pode ser vazio.

Comment: Não funcionou.  Obs. desculpe, quando disse que não funciona em lugar nenhum estava me referindo dentro do fluxo do spring security. se utilizo fora do fluxo do spring security funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tá usando o Spring Security e CDI, ambos possuem um contexto de injeção de dependência diferentes logo o DAO gerenciado pelo CDI não vai estar disponível para o contexto do Spring Security.
Em um projeto para contornar esse problema tive que usar  a seguinte classe para retornar os Beans que estão no contexto de injeção do CDI para o Spring Security poder usar corretamente.

```
public class CDIServiceLocator {

    private static BeanManager getBeanManager() {
        try {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            return (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/BeanManager");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Bean não encontrado no JNDI");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {
        BeanManager bm = getBeanManager();
        Set<Bean<?>> beans = (Set<Bean<?>>) bm.getBeans(clazz);

        if (beans == null || beans.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) beans.iterator().next();

        CreationalContext<T> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
        T o = (T) bm.getReference(bean, clazz, ctx);
        return o;
    }

}
```

**Dentro do método**  que vai usar o DAO coloque a seguinte chamada:

```
MeuDAO meuDAO = CDIServiceLocator.getBean(MeuDAO.class);
```

**Udate**

Onde está `java:comp/env/BeanManager` substitua por `java:comp/BeanManager`

Fiz um teste usando o Wildfly 10 e funcionou corretamente

Comment: Seria isso 
@Inject 
private UsuarioDao usuarioDao = CDIServiceLocator.getBean(UsuarioDao.class);

Comment: Esta dando Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Bean não encontrado no JNDI
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)

Comment: Não, você vai instanciar o dao dentro do método loadUserByUsername

Comment: Deu certo a alteração?

Comment: fiz assim dentro do metodo->  usuarioDao = CDIServiceLocator.getBean(UsuarioDao.class);  Usuario usuario = usuarioDao.consulta(email);  Compila, mas ao executar continua dando Bean não encontrado no JNDI

Comment: Cria uma arquivo context.xml dentro da pasta /webapp/META-INF  com esse conteudo: http://pastebin.com/tZsZy1Ds

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41573/discussion-between-marcelo-and-adelmo00).

Comment: @Marcelo fiz um update na resposta, veja se funciona.

Comment: Desculpe a demora no retorno.  
Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.
O que devo ler para compreender melhor a situação?